# using files from a specific directory Java

Tags: java, macros, imagej

I want to write a macro for Image J using Java
I have an error in the first line when trying to use the images from the specific folder, I don´t know how to solve it.

Source code:

```
for (File file : new File("E:\\Ghent\\magnel\\Bjorn\\cap 1").listFiles()) {

  if (file.isFile() && file.getName().toLowerCase().contains("cap")) {
    //imageCalculator("Subtract create", "cap run_0001.fits","DCBB.fits");
    imageCalculator("Subtract create",file.getName(),"DC.fits")
    //run("Image Calculator...", "image1=[cap run_0001.fits] operation=Subtract image2=DCBB.fits create");

    imageCalculator("Divide create", "Result of cap","DEN");
    //run("Image Calculator...", "image1=[Result of cap] operation=Divide image2=[DEN] create");
    saveAs(file.getName() . "_AD", "C:\\Users\\Nati\\Desktop\\prueba macro\\"_AD".tif");
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?Also, see if file.getAbsolutePath() works for you

Comment: This appears when I try to run the macro in ImageJ´.´ expected in line 1

Comment: @NOBDBBB Not very expert in ImageJ, but can strings be concatenated as they are in  `saveAs(file.getName() . "_AD", "C:\\Users\\Nati\\Desktop\\prueba macro\\"_AD".tif");` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be the use of `\`.
Try with `/` or `\\`.

e.g.

```
new File("E:/Ghent/magnel/Bjorn/cap 1")
```

Backslash is a special character in Java and many other languages, as you can read in [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I tried what you suggested and I still get ´.´ expected in line 1

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing **Java** and [**ImageJ1 macro language**](http://imagej.net/developer/macro/macros.html) in your code.

The error occurs because you are trying to run the code as an ImageJ macro, but the first line contains Java syntax.

You have two options:

- Convert your file system logic into IJ1 macro as well. See [here](http://imagej.net/Scripting_toolbox#Opening.2C_processing.2C_and_saving_a_sequence_of_files_in_a_folder) for an example how to process a folder with files.
- Compile and run your code as a Java plugin. You can use the [Macro recorder](http://imagej.net/Macro_recorder) in Java mode to get the required commands, e.g. for the Image Calculator:

  ```
  ImageCalculator ic = new ImageCalculator();
  ImagePlus imp1 = IJ.openImage(file.getName());
  ImagePlus imp2 = WindowManager.getImage("DC.fits");
  ImagePlus imp3 = ic.run("Subtract create", imp1, imp2);
  ```